# What is the meaning of "admitting a structure" in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the meaning of the following statement in algebra paper:

> The noncommutative Jordan superalgebras are in a one-to-one correspondence with the Jordan superalgebras admitting the Poisson bracket structure

I do not understand the meaning of **admitting**?

Comment: Context please?  Like the paper you found it in?

Comment: in non-associative algebras. in noncommutative Jordan superalgebras

Comment: I'm really looking for a more specific context than just a subject area.

Comment: A paper  titled SIMPLE FINITE-DIMENSIONAL NONCOMMUTATIVE
JORDAN SUPERALGEBRAS OF CHARACTERISTIC zero.

Comment: Thanks for providing that. Too bad I can't find the text online :(

Comment: Can you just take the trouble to  type into the question the full sentence where this occurs. Even the complete paragraph?

Comment: The whole sentence would be great, and if the sentences before and after are short, they would be appareciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the example you have given a little confusing, which may stem from the fact you're trying to generate an example while imperfectly understanding the term.

The word "admit" is being used in the sense of the fourth entry of the verb 'admit' [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/admit?s=t), to allow.  The phrase "X admits a Y structure" means that it is possible to define operations on X so that the axioms of a Y structure.

For example, no set of order 6 admits the structure of a field, because it is known all finite fields have prime power order.

Similarly, there is no $3$ dimensional real algebra that admits the structure of a division ring [the Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)).

But on the other hand, every abelian group $G$ admits a left module structure where the ring $R=End(G)$, because you can define $f\cdot g:=f(g)$ for every $f\in End(G)$ and $g\in G$.

Another positive example: every associative algebra admits a Lie algebra structure, namely the bracket given by the commutator product.